# Update posts to reflect Stack Exchange data dump hosted by the Internet Archive

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, data-dump

I have updated a couple of answers with the new data dump location.  I suggest reviewing and updating a few of the dozen or so questions/answers that refer to old locations, that suggested Amazon, etc.  Perhaps a query *something similar to the following*:

> "data dump" & (Amazon | clearbits | future | location)

And notifying interested individuals in such threads.

Suggested update text is below.

---

> **Update**

According to the blog, *["Stack Exchange Creative Commons data now hosted by the Internet Archive"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/)* (Jan 2014), the Stack Exchange data dump is located here:

> [Stack Exchange Data Dump at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

*(The clearbits link no longer works.)*

---

*<sup>(Is it ok to make such a suggestion? I'm still new on mso, so if there is anything incorrect about the way I have submitted or worded this, please feel free to take any action to remedy.)</sup>*